# how to initialize the recursive function for length

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
int countChars(string str)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (str == "")
        return count;
    else
    {
        count++;// add a character to the count
        return count + countChars(str.substr(1));// function calls itself
    }
}
```

I need to take the above function and call in in the program below and I'm not sure how to initialize it properly. Below is what I tried and it doesn't work. I'm not allowed to use the `.length()` because otherwise the program would be done.

```
int main()
{
    char find = '\0';
    string str;
    int count = 0;
    int length = int(countChars);

    //ask the user for a sentence 
    cout << "Enter a sentence " << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    //ask the user which letter they want the count of 
    cout << "Which letter would you like to find the number of appearances: " << endl;
    cin >> find;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == find)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "the letter " << find << " appears " << length << " times " << endl;

    //waits for user to exit
    system("pause");
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I suppose you know this but, this is a proper example for the silliest competition. I'm giving a close vote based on the silliness.

Comment: @Alycia  It is totally unclear what you are trying to do with the function.

Comment: `int length = int(countChars);` what?

Comment: you init `length` in the (imho) most funny way, then you read in some string from the user, pretend that `lenght` is the lenght of that string and finally you pretend that it is the nuber of occurences of a letter without ever setting it to a meaningful value. That is a real multi-purpose variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function should count the number of appearances of a letter in a string. If so then it is declared and defined incorrectly. It has to have at least two parameters an object of type `std::string` and an object of type `char`.

Here is shown how such a recursive function can look

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t countChars( const std::string &s, char c )
{
    return s.empty() ? 0 : ( s[0] == c ) + countChars( { s, 1 }, c );
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter a sentence ";

    std::string s;

    std::getline( std::cin, s );

    std::cout << "Which letter would you like to find the number of appearances: ";

    char c = '\0';

    std::cin >> c;


    std::cout << "The letter " << c 
              << " appears " << countChars( s, c ) 
              << " times " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a sentence My name is Alycia
Which letter would you like to find the number of appearances: a
The letter a appears 2 times
```

If you mean a function that just calculates the length of a string then it can look like

```
size_t countChars( const std::string &s )
{
    return s.empty() ? 0 : 1 + countChars( { s, 1 } );
}
```

and shall be called after the statement

```
getline(cin, str);
```

Comment: The op is obviously new to C++ or even programming in general and it's not very helpful to post a complex solution like that. You can't jst use ternary operators and list initialization without a comment and expect a beginner to know what's going on here.